# replace keyword with looping through records from database

Tags: python

I have python code which reads file looks for a keyword to replace then writes to file replacing the keyword with an empty string  and then appends the file looping through database records.

Rather than having an append function i was wondering if it would be possible to loop through my database records and replace directly in my write function.

I had tried replacing empty string part with r which is my record set but it only replaces with the last record from my database query.

#### Read function to replace keyword with empty string at end of file

```
with open(ffile, "r") as feedfile:
    filedata = feedfile.read()
    newdata = filedata.replace("ENDOFFILE", "")
    feedfile.close()
```

#### Write Function to replace keyword with empty string at end of file

```
with open(ffile, "w") as feedfile:
    feedfile.write(newdata)
    feedfile.close()
```

#### apped function to loop through database records to end of file

```
with open(ffile, "a") as feedfile:
    for record in mylist:
        for r in record:
            d = {None: ''}
            record = [d.get(x, x) for x in record]
            r = '\t'.join([x for x in record if x is not None])
        feedfile.write(r + '\n')
    feedfile.write("ENDOFFILE")
    feedfile.close()
```

my desired output is:

```
record1
record2
record3
ENDOFFILE
```

Just to reiterate, the above code works but is it possible to get rid of the append function and adapt the write function with looping through my database query records.

Comment: One thing to mention, you do not need the `file.close()` at the end of every code block because you are using the context manager (with block). The `with` automatically closes the file.

Comment: ***"get rid of the append function"***: Ther is no `.append(...` in your code? If i get it right, you write `"ENDOFILE"`, next time you want to append records at the file position just before `"ENDOFILE"`. Therefore you have to `position` the file pointer using [lseek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.lseek) to set it relative to the end of the file, e.g. `.lseek(feedfile, -8, SEEK_END)`

Comment: I am appending to the file with new database records but will always need "ENDOFILE" at the end of the file, so the way i'm dong this to the file is reading to search for the keyword "ENDOFILE" and then overwriting the keyword with  empty string "" which removes the keyword and then i can append my new database records along with "ENDOFILE" again at the end.

Comment: @rob: Using `lseek` you don't have to reread/wirte the file first. You can *append* new records at once.

Comment: OK i will try to find out how to apply lseek to my query and try thanks